# Spring Data Neo4j Relationships gets overridden

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have an Entity "**Parent**" which has a relationship with 4 Set of > "**Children**".
On **Neo4jRepository** save method ids of some of the related children return null. To be more precise it has different behavior on every call to save method e.g times it saved three of the lists correctly but return null for the ids of one set of children.

[api response in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3R2e.png)

Comment: Can you share the code of the models and the save method call?

Comment: @CharchitKapoor please have a look now I have edited the post to include the code for model classes.